# Inserting images into current img tags

Tags: javascript

I am generating cats. What is happening now is every time `generateCat()` is run, `cats-container` div is cleared and then new `img` tags are inserted.
I believe this is a very slow way of doing this, is there any other way to "replace" these src without having to add id to every image and changing their `src=""`?

### HTML

```
    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="header-challenge">
                <h2>Challenge 2: Cat generator</h2>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div class="button-challenge-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cats-button">Generate</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="cats-container">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/401" alt="cat 1">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/601/400" alt="cat 2">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/402" alt="cat 3">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/602/400" alt="cat 4">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/600/403" alt="cat 5">
            <img class="cat-image" src="http://theoldreader.com/kittens/603/400" alt="cat 6">
        </div>

    </div>
```

### Js

```
const catButton = document.getElementById("cats-button")
const catsContainer = document.getElementById("cats-container")

const generateCat = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
        while(catsContainer.firstChild){
            catsContainer.removeChild(catsContainer.firstChild);
        }
    if (target.matches("button")) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var newImg = new Image (240,200);
            newImg.classList.add("cat-image");
            newImg.src = "http://theoldreader.com/kittens/"
            +getRndInteger(500,600)+"/"+getRndInteger(500,600)+""
            catsContainer.appendChild(newImg); 
        }
    }
}
catButton.addEventListener("click", generateCat);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `img` elements using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then change the `src` property, like so:

```
const generateCat = () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".cat-image")
  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.src = "http://theoldreader.com/kittens/"+getRndInteger(500,600)+"/"+getRndInteger(500,600)+""
  })
}
```